# In Spring Boot, how to reset the metrics registry before each test?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I have tests and want to make assertions against micrometer metrics, but the tests run in random order so I want to reset or clear all the micrometer metrics before each test so my assertion are always correct.

Answer (score 9):

It depends on the Meter registry used. If you are using a `SimpleMeterRegistry` you could do:

```
registry.getMeters().forEach((meter) -> registry.remove(meter))
```

Comment: Same but more concise and works for any MeterRegistry: `registry.clear()`. Actually removes the meters rather than resets their values.

Comment: Turn this into a separate answer and I'll be happy to upvote.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`clear()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.micrometer/micrometer-core/1.8.2/io/micrometer/core/instrument/MeterRegistry.html#clear()) method

```
registry.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to mock meter registry, since they are monitoring and should not affect your business logic and used for alerting.
In case that doesn't help:

for gauge you can reset values

```
AtomicInteger myGauge = meterRegistry.gauge("numberGauge", new AtomicInteger(0));
myGauge.set(0);
```

for counter, reinitialize,

```
counter = meterRegistry.counter(counter.toString());
```

Reference: https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_manually_incrementingdecrementing_a_gauge

Comment: meterRegistry.counter() wont reinitialize counter, it creates or return existing counter